# ValueError: Plan shapes are not aligned -> when using pd.concat()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am posting this question because unfortunately the previous answers to this question didn't solve my problem.

I am trying to concatenate four dataframes containing numeric values and a date index column. The date index columns for all dataframes is the same, but some of the column names are different.

**Example** (in reality there are more columns but this shouldn't make a difference):

```
df1 columns = ['DateIndex', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
df2 columns = ['DateIndex', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G']
df3 columns = ['DateIndex', 'Z', 'J', 'K']
df4 columns = ['DateIndex', 'B', 'I', 'M']

code: data = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3, df4], axis=0, join='outer')
```

I then receive the following error:

```
ValueError: Plan shapes are not aligned
```

I have checked for duplicate column names in all the dataframes and also checked for different indices by setting them to the same value using the following code:

```
df1 = df1[df1.index.isin(df2.index)] -> (for every dataframe)
```

*Background context:* The command used to work, but I am experiencing problems since the columns of one of the dataframes has changed (gone from 10 to 47 columns).

Comment: in the dataframe in which the columns has gone from 10 to 47 , check if there are duplicate column names.

Comment: Yes, maybe it was unclear but I have already done this and there are no duplicate columns names.